# How to display objects in ascending order on tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Bookstore project with separate classes for Book and Bookstore, and then a master view controller and a corresponding detail view controller. At the moment, it displays the list of books from an array of books called bookList, but I want to change it so that the list of books appear in ascending order.

I think the code to change the bookList array should be `bookList.sorted() { $0.title < $1.title }`
but I don't know where to place it so that it appears in the view in ascending order according to title.

I tried placing this code in the `viewDidLoad` of the `DetailViewController` by adding var myBookStore = BookStore() to top of the class and then calling `bookList.sorted() { $0.title < $1.title }` in the viewDidLoad method but this says `Result of call to 'sorted(by:)' is unused`

Book Class

```
class Book {
    var title: String
    var author: String
    var description: String
    var price: Double


    init(title: String, author: String, description: String, price: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

BookStore model class:

```
class BookStore {
    var bookList: [Book] = [] //bookList is an array which allows us to add a series of objects - Book objects :)

    var book1 = Book(title: "Z to A in weird words", author: "Arthur Doyle", description: "standout strange words", price: 30.95)
    var book2 = Book(title: "Cave Life", author: "Samuel Stone", description: "Outliving coronavirus", price: 10.00)
    var book3 = Book(title: "Andy Warhol: the biography", author: "Bal Smith", description: "the artist's life", price: 5.00)


    init() {
        bookList += [book1, book2, book3]
        }
```

Detail View Contoller:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

    var myBookStore = BookStore()


    //convenience method
    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.

        if let myBook = detailItem { 
            titleLabel.text = myBook.title
            authorLabel.text = myBook.author
            descriptionTextView.text = myBook.description
            priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", myBook.price)

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureView()

        myBookStore.bookList.sorted() { $0.title < $1.title }

    }

    var detailItem: Book? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.

        }
    }


}
```

Master View Controller:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = [Any]()

    var myBookStore = BookStore()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @objc
    func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
        objects.insert(NSDate(), at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    // MARK: - Segues


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let selectedBook: Book = myBookStore.bookList[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = selectedBook
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                detailViewController = controller
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myBookStore.bookList.count
    }

    //tip: look for default provided object to replace this with your object
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = myBookStore.bookList[indexPath.row].title
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Default text"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first, `.sorted()` returns a sorted copy of whatever you give it. That's why Xcode is warning you that the result is unused — it's returning a new array, and you're not assigning it to a variable or using it anywhere. In order to sort in-place, you can use `.sort()` instead. If you just change sorted to sort in your current code, it will work until you add a new book to `bookList`, but I will say that it's not a good idea.

(If your `bookList` will be static, then it would be fine, and I would simply move the `.sort()` call to the end of your `BookStore` initializer in order to maintain proper separation of concerns.)

You could use a computed variable in your model that returns a sorted copy of `bookList` and use it instead:

```
var bookListSorted: [Book] {
    bookList.sorted() { $0.title < $1.title }
}
```

Which will work if you have a small `bookList`, but it's not great either, because every time you ask for a count, or index into it, it will be recomputed, which can get expensive very quickly.

What I would recommend instead is to not allow your `bookList` to be modified from outside your model class (`private(set) var bookList: [Book]`), and instead provide functions in your model class to add, edit, or delete entries in `bookList`. You can sort in-place after making any change, or if you need the most efficiency, then you need to start thinking about implementing [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the proper index for a new entry and then insert it at that index.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful. I'm just a couple of weeks into this and learning by doing, while following a book. Huge thanks again.